wireguard server
есть сервер 91.199.154.110
раздает 10.7.0.0/32
два роутера подключенных к серверу через туннель
первый 192.168.3.1
второй 192.168.2.1
не могу пингануть с 3.1 - 3.2 и наоборот не могу получить доступ к ним
в сети
[Peer]
PublicKey =
PresharedKey =
AllowedIPs = 10.7.0.8/32, 192.168.3.0/24, 192.168.0.0/24,
END_PEER k1
BEGIN_PEER k2
[Peer]
PublicKey =
PresharedKey =
AllowedIPs = 10.7.0.9/32, 192.168.2.0/24,
ЧТО НЕ ТАК?(((
на клиентах Allowed IPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
